# Using WebDAV to list files on NextCloud server results in method not supported

Tags: python, webdav, nextcloud

I'm trying to list files using webdab but I'm having issues.  I can create directories and put files just fine but not list a directory or pull a file. I'm seeing the error, "Method not supported".

```
from webdav3.client import Client
options = {
  'webdav_hostname': "https://___________.com/remote.php/dav/files/",
  'webdav_login': "user_name",
  'webdav_password': "password"
}
client = Client(options)
print(client.list('/'))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/<user>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webdav3/client.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    res = fn(self, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/<user>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webdav3/client.py", line 264, in list
    response = self.execute_request(action='list', path=directory_urn.quote())
  File "/home/<user>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webdav3/client.py", line 228, in execute_request
    raise MethodNotSupported(name=action, server=self.webdav.hostname)
webdav3.exceptions.MethodNotSupported: Method 'list' not supported for https://________.com/remote.php/dav/files
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `client.list()` method assumes the [remote root directory by default](https://github.com/ezhov-evgeny/webdav-client-python-3/blob/develop/webdav3/client.py#L245).
As you supply `https://___________.com/remote.php/dav/files/` as your `webdav_hostname` the root directory it tries to access when you call `client.list('/')` is the top level files directory. As a Nextcloud user you don't have access to that level, so listing that is impossible. However, you do have access to the `files/<username>` directory, so listing `client.list('/<username>/')` works.

To prevent that you have prepend the username to every list command you can set the `webdav_hostname` to `.../remote.php/dav/files/<username>`. Then a call to `client.list()` should work straight away.

Answer (score 1):

Despite already providing a username in the webdav_login, a username is still needed in the call to `listdir`. For example, to get a list of files in the root directory of the user "user_name", `client.list('/user_name/')`.

Comment: I can't suggest edits now, so therefore a comment. The solution seems right, but it's not because you need to provide a username (the [`list`](https://github.com/ezhov-evgeny/webdav-client-python-3/blob/develop/webdav3/client.py#L245) method does not have a username argument) it's because you need to provide the root folder that needs to be listed, *which in this instance* coincides with the username. This could probably also be resolved by adding the username after `..../dav/files/` in the webdav hostname.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I just tried it and it works as you said. Post this as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import nc_py_api

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create Nextcloud client instance class
    nc = nc_py_api.Nextcloud(nextcloud_url="http://nextcloud.local", nc_auth_user="admin", nc_auth_pass="admin")

    def list_dir(directory):
        # usual recursive traversing over directories
        for node in nc.files.listdir(directory):
            if node.is_dir:
                list_dir(node)
            else:
                print(f"{node.user_path}")

    print("Files on the instance for the selected user:")
    list_dir("")
    exit(0)
```

This is an example of how to navigate through a directory and all its child directories.

A little clarification: we define `listdir` to call it recursively for each directory.

After that we call it with an empty parameter to look at the user's root directory and it will call itself for each subdirectory and print the files in it.

Also the DAV protocol supports the `depth` parameter for listing, so `nc_py_api` also supports it, and you can perform:

```
nc.files.listdir(path="relative user path", depth=-1)
```

to get all the files and directories.

*Just a note: in most cases it is better to use `find` to get the list of files you need with a specified condition, since this will only require one network request to the Nextcloud instance and sorting of files by condition will be performed on server.*

Answer (score -1):

Another alternative is to try os.scandir(), which is sometimes a sufficient method for listing files on the Nextcloud server, and is available in Python.

Comment: wouldn't this require you to ssh into the server first?

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).